# Deluge: missing systray icon in XFCE Panel (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, system-tray, deluge

I installed the latest Deluge version, i enabled both "enable tray icon" and "minimize in tray when closing", but i can't see any tray icon and if i close the program i can't see anything at all and if i want to open it again i have to start it again with its executable.
I have Xubuntu 14.04 LTS x64, xfce4-panel 4.11.0 and i can see any other tray icon (at this moment i see Dropbox, Pidgin and Whatpulse, but if i open Audacious, it shows its tray icon without issues).

Any suggestion?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: There is a known issue in Xfce whereas certain apps [disappear from the systray](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11298) for no good reason. Maybe you hit that.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved it.
I disabled "enable application indicator" and magically the tray icon showed in systray area.

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by removing the "Indicator Plugin" and adding the "Status Notifier Plugin"